# Custom methods don't EVER get callled, even when annotations are on the method?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my Entity objects I put all JPA annotations on fields. They work well with Project Lombok which generates all getters and setters for me, greatly simplifying my code.

**EDIT:**

This seems to also be happening when I move the annotation down to the method

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = ChannelDAOHb.class, mappedBy = "server", orphanRemoval = true)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
public Set<ChannelDAO> getChannels() {
    System.out.println("Getting some channels");
    ...
}

getChannels().add(new Channel("someChannel")); //Nothing printed here
```

However it seems the custom getter for one of my OneToMany association fields isn't being called. Even something destructive like this

```
public Set<ChannelDAO> getChannels() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Take that, Hibernate");
}

getChannels().add(new Channel("someChannel"));
```

That exception NEVER gets thrown.

What's going on here? Why isn't my getter being called?

Comment: @Marcelo No my field isn't public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate uses reflection by default. Methods are only for your own API. This reduces scaffolding needed for setting up persistent layer.

Comment: No, I meant that calling `getChannels()` from my own code doesn't net that exception. I should of clarified this in the question

Comment: @TheLQ ok, Hibernate actually creates proxy classes inheriting over your entity to be able to handle lazy methods that manage relationships, and your `getChannels()` method will be overriden by the lazy-loading behavior.

Comment: @Marcelo Great... Does that mean I have to move all the JPA annotations to getters now?

Comment: @TheLQ No, try setting your relationship up as a Fetch.Eager to see if this behavior changes.

Comment: @Marcelo Doesn't seem to affect anything. Looks like I'll need to use getters then. Really sucks that Lombocks onMethod parameter isn't supported in Netbeans as it would make things a bit simpler. BTW, Move what you said to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @TheLQ: You've already accepted this answer, but I just have to say that I've never seen anything like this in ~5 years of using Hibernate. I've most always used field access, and currently I annotate the entity fields, not methods, just as you described. While I'm at a loss to explain exactly what's going on, I don't believe the answer is accurate. Hibernate's proxying definitely doesn't get in the way of your code under normal circumstances. Can you put a small, runnable sample project somewhere like Github? I'm really interested to see this problem.

Comment: @Ryan No problem at all with 'dis'-accepting my answer. It's not complete and was based on invalid assumptions. Your comments provide better answer for sure.

Comment: Between answer and comments, you can take this as an accepted answer, sorry we couldn't help.

Comment: Makes sense. Btw, I made answer community wiki so if you feel so you could update it. It will be useful by other people who have the same question.

Comment: @TheLQ, @Marcelo, @Petro: I've created an example project on github using Hibernate 3.6.5.Final which shows that calling a getter on a proxy executes the actual code in the getter. If you have git and maven, you can try it out:
"`git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp`"
"`cd tmp`"
"`mvn compile exec:java -D exec.mainClass=rds.testbed.hibernateproxies.Main -pl hibernate-proxies`"

Comment: @TheLQ: I've tried project posted by Ryan and looks like methods are executed even if hibernate proxy is used. I can't make it to use direct field access from proxy using Access/AccessType annotations. Could you please share your sample project somewhere on github so we could take a look.